# how to set socks proxy with username and password in the proxy setting

Tags: proxy, socks5

i have a proxy server `exampleuser:examplepassword@serverip:serverport` and i want to use it with the network proxy server in setting>network>proxy but using `exampleuser:examplepassword@serverip` as the socks host and `serverport` and the port dosn't work. how do i use the proxy password.